# Grouping with PersistedFaceIds in Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

The documentation states that grouping can be done on `FaceIds`. Does it work with `PersistedFaceIds` of a given `FaceList`. If not, what method can be employed to group the `PersistedFaceIds` within a `FaceList`.

Answer (score 0):

PersistedFaceIds are FaceIds that do not expire.  FaceLists also do not expire.  You would be able accomplish this